Is it possible to have sandboxed users between Firestore apps within a single Project?
I developped an app backed by a firestore DB with firestore functions triggering on some particular events made by my users.
I am considering to decline this app on "dedicated instances" (= tenant) for some of my customers, who would like to play with their own firestore databases and users.
I've seen that since firestore functions v2, we can now control the database an event is triggered from, which makes me think I could implement multi tenancy through dedicated firestore databases.
BUT (and I guess that's a strong BUT) it looks like I can only have 1 and only 1 Firestore Authentication configuration within a Firestore Project (in https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<projectId>/authentication/users).
Meaning that all users from my different customers/multi tenants would be mangled into a single (shared) database.
This is also corroborated by the fact that we don't seem to be able to restrict (or get) the database in identity-based firestore functions (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.identity)
Is my assumption correct ? or do you see some other options I would have missed ?
If I'm right, it means that I wouldn't have any other choice than creating 1 firestore project per tenant, to ensure users are never shared across my tenants.

The security rules can be configured in https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/databases/<database-name>/rules which suggests it's per-database. I'm not sure whether you're thinking of those rules or other ones though...

Nope, I'm rather thinking about the Authentication part https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<project id>/authentication/users

check Google Identity Platform, which supports multi-tentant  as suggested here, Also check link1 & link2

The set of users that Firebase Authentication records per process really don't have anything at all to do with any specific Firestore database.  Firebase Auth uses its own internal "database" of sorts to manage the entire set of users, which is completely separate from Firestore.  There is no "mangling", as you say.
If you do want to create Firestore instances that are to be used only by certain users, it's up to your application logic to enforce that.  You are certainly free to try to implement that using security rules that determine which users can read and write which database instances when the access is coming directly from your web or mobile application.  But those security rules don't apply when access come from your backend - your backend will need logic to determine what to access for any given user/tenant.
You haven't given enough information in your question to know if it's absolutely required to create a separate project per tenant.  But it is very common to do so, as that's the only way to truly enforce tenant-database access with minimal additional application logic coded by the developer of such a system.  In the end, it's up to you to determine if it's worthwhile to write application logic to handle per-tenant logic in a single project, or build some infrastructure that uses multiple project.  It really can go either way: it's your call.
